# C++/CLI nullptr incorrectly treated as "int"

Tags: c++-cli

I am writing a managed wrapper in C++/CLI (VS2010) for a third-party unmanaged library.  In the code, I have a method that looks like this:

```
if(oldState != _state && UnitStateChanged != nullptr)
    UnitStateChanged(this, gcnew UnitStateChangedEventArgs(oldState, _state));
```

The "nullptr" generates the following error:

> error C2446: '!=' : no conversion from 'int' to 'UnitStateChangedEventHandler ^'

The compiler seems to treat any use of "nullptr" as an "int", even on something as simple as this:

```
Object^ temp = nullptr;
```

Everything i've read indicates that the compiler will figure it out on it's own, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Is there a setting that I'm missing (other than /clr or #pragma managed)?

Comment: It would help if you could give the smallest "full" program that displayed the error so we could build and see for ourselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone without a C++11 compiler wrote

```
#define nullptr (0)
```

somewhere in a header file?

(The usual macro is `#define NULL (0)`)

---

This is, of course, forbidden.

[image: Standard section 17.6.4.3.1, forbidden using keywords as macro names]
[image: list of C++11 keywords (Table 4 from the Standard)]

Comment: Good call!  Sounds like the most likely.

Comment: This was exactly the problem.  The third-party library had it defined deep in one of the headers.

Comment: Incidentally, my solution was simply to add a `#define nullptr nullptr` before the third-party include (they use ifndef).  Is there a more elegant way of handling this?

Comment: @seairth: You mean aside from filing a bug report, with the above sections of the Standard enclosed?

Comment: `#undef nullptr` after the third-party include might also do the trick. The third-party library would be compiled with literal zeros like it wants, and your code would use the proper nullptr.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's only for C++11.  The third-party library was written with VC++ 8.  I will definitely pass this along to them, but I wouldn't consider it a "bug".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to fire an event.

In C#, there's a standard idiom for firing an event while protecting against null reference exceptions and multithreading modification:

```
// C#
EventHandler handler = this.MyEvent;
if(handler != null)
    handler(this, new EventArgs(foo));
```

It looks like you're trying to re-create that in C++/CLI, but it's unnecessary. In C++/CLI, an event will emit three 'inner methods' (is that the proper name for them?) called `add`, `remove`, and `raise`. In C#, it creates `add` and `remove` only, no explicit raise, which is why we have to write that block of code over and over.

Here's an event defined in C++/CLI, and what .NET Reflector sees when it decompiles it:

```
// C++/CLI:
public ref class Test
{
public:
    event EventHandler^ MyEvent;
};


// Decompiled to C#:
public class Test
{
    // Fields
    private EventHandler <backing_store>MyEvent;

    // Events
    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] add
        {
            this.<backing_store>MyEvent = (EventHandler) Delegate.Combine(this.<backing_store>MyEvent, value);
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] remove
        {
            this.<backing_store>MyEvent = (EventHandler) Delegate.Remove(this.<backing_store>MyEvent, value);
        }
        raise
        {
            EventHandler <tmp> = null;
            <tmp> = this.<backing_store>MyEvent;
            if (<tmp> != null)
            {
                <tmp>(value0, value1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `raise` inner method is doing the null check for you, so you can skip doing it, and just fire the event without checking.

```
if(oldState != _state)
    this->UnitStateChanged(this, gcnew UnitStateChangedEventArgs(oldState, _state));
```

Comment: While this wasn't my issue, I truly appreciate this information!  I'm making that change right now.

Comment: Though, once I fixed the original issue, an issue related to your comment did occur.  The `UnitStateChanged != nullptr` resulted in the following error:  _error C3918: usage requires 'Unit::UnitStateChanged' to be a data member_.  Thanks again!